# Automate The Boring Stuff with Python Ch 4 myPets

Tags: python

I am currently working through *Automate the Boring Stuff with Python* and was given this example in Chapter 4 (You can read the page [here](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter4/) if you're curious). The code was typed from the example given in the book as suggested and is pasted below. In the book, I am told the response I get is supposed to prompt me to enter a pet name, and if it doesn't match what's in the list I should get a response saying that I don't have a pet by that name.

The problem I run into is that the response I ACTUALLY get is :

```
Enter a pet name:
Gennie
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gillian/Documents/Python/AutomateTheBoringStuffwithPython/Ch4Example1.py", line 3, in <module>
    name = str(input())
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Gennie' is not defined
```

I'm not sure why that would be. I don't see anything different about my code from the example, but something about that error seems not right. Can anyone tell me where I've gone off course?

```
myPets = ['Zophie', 'Pooka', 'Fat-tail']
print('Enter a pet name: ')
name = input()
if name not in myPets:
    print('I do not have a pet named ' + name)
else:
    print(name + ' is my pet.')
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using? I bet you're using Python 2.7. The book is probably designed for Python 3, which has slightly different syntax.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between raw\_input() and input() in python3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x)

Comment: `input()` in Python2 will evaluate the given input string, so if you type `Gennie` it will try to replace it with the value of a variable with the same name. This nonsense has been fixed in Python3.

Comment: Also the return value of `input()` in Python3 is already of type `str`, so a cast conversion to `str` isn't really needed.

Comment: Use raw_input() it will solve the error. For more info use link provided by @Guillaume Also if you input "Genie" in string format it will work just FYI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `input()` into `raw_input()` as you seem to be using python 2.x and this code is written in 3.x.

Find out more about differences [here](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_python_2_3_key_diff.html).